# Yii: NestedSetBehavior::parent не возвращает родительский узел

Tags: php, yii

**NestedSetBehavior:** Компонент-обёртка для работы с деревьями.
При выполнении метода **parent()** возвращает не родителя, а узел для которого ищу родителя.

Полез в код компонента, а потом в ядро фреймворка.
Проблема в том что в parent() выполняется получение критериев

```
$criteria=$owner->getDbCriteria();
```

который возвращает дефолтные настройки, точнее limit -1

Косяк ли это? За чем это нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

из мануала

> #### Выборка предка узла
>
> Используем метод
> `NestedSetBehavior::parent()`:
>
> ~~~php
> $category=Category::model()->findByPk(9);
> $parent=$category->parent()->find();
> ~~~
>
> Результат:
>
> Объект Active Record, который
> характеризует узел Cars.